# Delete Data JSON from table MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

Hi I need to remove from a json table everything that contains the name weapon_pistol50 , this is one of my tables in mysql

`{"weapons":[{"ammo":74,"name":"WEAPON_PISTOL50"},{"ammo":118,"name":"WEAPON_PISTOL50"},{"ammo":54,"name":"WEAPON_PISTOL"}]}`

The table is named: datastore_data

and the column that contains json format is called data.

I want to update all the tables by deleting this from the json: '{"ammo":118,"name":"WEAPON_PISTOL50"}'

I haven't tested many variables for now, but I need to do the above.

Comment: Use the `JSON_SEARCH()` function in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution tested on MySQL 8.0:

```
update datastore_data cross join json_table(data, '$.weapons[*]' 
  columns( 
    i for ordinality, 
    ammo int path '$.ammo', 
    name varchar(20) path '$.name'
  )
) as j 
set data = json_remove(data, concat('$.weapons[', j.i-1, ']')) 
where j.ammo = 118 and j.name = 'WEAPON_PISTOL50';
```

If you are using a version of MySQL too old to support JSON_TABLE(), then it's a lot harder.

Frankly, it would be far easier if you didn't use JSON. Instead, store one weapon per row in a second table with normal columns named `ammo` and `name`.

```
create table weapons(
  id serial primary key,
  owner_id int,
  ammo int,
  name varchar(20)
);
```

Then you could do this task much more simply:

```
delete from weapons
where ammo = 118 and name = 'WEAPON_PISTOL50';
```

Storing data in JSON documents might seem like a convenient way to load complex data into a single row of a single table, but virtually every task you have to do with that data afterwards becomes a lot harder than if you had used normal tables and columns.

Comment: 19:13:02 update datastore_data cross join json_table(data, '$.weapons[*]'    columns(      i for ordinality,      name varchar(20) path '$.name'   ) ) as j  set data = json_remove(data, concat('$.weapons[', j.i-1, ']'))  where j.name = 'WEAPON_SPECIALCARBINE' Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(data, '$.weapons[*]'    columns(      i for ordinality,      name varchar(20) p' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?