SQL query to update JSON field value in MySQL
Using MySQL, I need to update record where there is a null value in a field of type json. For example,
Table 1



Column A
Column B




Cell 1
[{"id":1, "name":"abc"},{"id":2, "name":"xyz"},{"id":3, "name":null}]


Cell 2
[{"id":4, "name":"test 1"},{"id":5, "name":null}]



Table 2



id
name




1
abc


2
xyz


3
null


4
test 1


5
null



I wrote this query to first retrieve the records where null value is stored in name key
SELECT *
FROM table 1
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(column B, '{"name": null}', '$');

Now I need to update the records using an SQL query to delete the object from the array in table 1 column B.
Table 1 should like this.
Table 1



Column A
Column B




Cell 1
[{"id":1, "name":"abc"},{"id":2, "name":"xyz"}]


Cell 2
[{"id":4, "name":"test 1"}]



How can I achieve this without writing stored procedures?
I tried updating one record using this query
UPDATE table 1
SET column_B = JSON_ARRAY(
    JSON_OBJECT(
       "id", JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(column_B, '$[0].id')), 
       "name", JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(injuries, '$[0].name'))
    ),
)
WHERE id = 1;


Which purpose has table2? You don't use it in your sql's. If a cell contains multiple or even only names with NULL, should they all be removed, even if this would make the entire column NULL for this row?

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71743929/20860

table2 is the main table from where the data is fetched to stored in table1 column B, and yes if the cell contains multiple name null values all should be removed and if cell has only one object with name null the entire column will be null for the row.

After lots of research & investigation, I found the solution ... Please check @tech_learner

There is a JSON function JSON_TABLE, which used to convert each JSON array into number of JSON Objects(rows) contains in that JSON Array. Let if a JSON array contact n JSON object, then it'll create n rows for Each Object which exists in that JSON array.
For Example:
Lets, my Input is:

I want to break as follows: 

set @jsonArray = JSON_ARRAY(
     JSON_OBJECT('key', 1, 'value', 'Data1'), 
     JSON_OBJECT('key', 2, 'value', 'Data2'), 
     JSON_OBJECT('key', 3, 'value', 'Data3')
);

select * 
from JSON_TABLE(
    @jsArray, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
        split_json_array JSON PATH '$'
    )
) AS JT

Similar way we need to convert all 'Column B' JSON array value into respective format. Then we have to apply condition, split_json_array->>'$.name' = 'null' filter 'Column B' JSON Array elements, which name is exits, and then need to merge those data.
So, respective query is:
WITH Base_Table_1 AS (
    select * from 
        Table_1,
        JSON_TABLE(column_B, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
            split_json_array JSON PATH '$'
        )) AS jt
),
filter_Table_1 AS (
    SELECT
        column_A,
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(split_json_array) AS column_B_filtered_data
    from Base_Table_1
    where split_json_array->>'$.name' != 'null'
    group by column_A
)
Select * from filter_Table_1;

Output: 

Next update your Table_1 table column_B value from filter_Table_1 table:
UPDATE Table_1
SET column_B = (
    select filter_Table_1.column_B_filtered_data
    From filter_Table_1
    WHERE Table_1.column_A = filter_Table_1.column_A
);

So, latest Table_1 is showing as:
select * from Table_1;


Sample code for live testing: myCompiler
Needs lots of research & investigation for this and I learn something new related to MySQL JSON Data handling.
I hope your issue will resolve. 
Thank you for this question.
